# Calculated Date Issue

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I created a calculated column and enter this formula:

```
=DATEDIF([Column 1],[Column 2],"d")
```

I picked the columns from the list to the right of the formula block.  When I entered this, it gave an error that the `syntax wasn't correct`.  Also when I went to the column, it showed `#Name` as the value.

Also, I have it selected as a number column as output.  One last thing, when I click ok and go back to the formula, it removes the bracket from one of the columns, i.e. `=DATEDIF(Column 1,[Column 2],"d")`.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. This is for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Also, I have it selected as a number column as output.  One last thing, when I click ok and go back to the formula, it removes the bracket from one of the columns, i.e. =DATEDIF(Column 1,[Column 2],"d").

Answer (score 2):

**Try to make sure the following:**

- Make sure that the two fields are `DateTime` fields.
- Make sure that the `Column1` is **less than or equal to** `Column2` otherwise, you will get `#NUM!` or `#NAME!` based on the datatype of the field.

**Example:**

Consider your formula like this

```
=DATEDIF([Start Date],[Due Date],"d")
```

So to get it worked without any issue, you should make sure that the first column in the formula (`in this case, [Start Date]`) is **less than or equal to** the second column (`in this case, [Due Date]`)

So as shown below the blue highlighted is **true** because the `[Start Date]` is **less than** `[Due Date]`

[image]

Comment: Yes, both data fields are date/time fields and I have Submitted date is less than or equal to Request Completed.

Comment: do you still face the issue?

Comment: I get #Value in the cell now.

Comment: share with me your current formula

Comment: =DATEDIF([SUBMITTEDDATE],[REQUESTCOMPLETED],"d")

Comment: Are you sure both columns have value? and the columns name provided correctly!

Comment: Not sure how to flag as correct.  Your answer solve my problem.

Comment: @PBRT Glad to hear it helped you, to flag as correct you can click on the true sign beside my answer then upvote the answer with the up arrow also beside my answer , also you can check how to accept and upvote answer here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2013 and i cannot reproduce your issue.

I created calculated column like the following:

[image]

Then it displays the correct number:

[image]

For your issue, please offer screenshots about your calculated column and your list to further troubleshoot the issue.

Besides, try to create an new list, create calculated column in the new list and compare the results.